# Display indirect (2nd degree) relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 questions
I can do simple queries on data that is in the nodes properties.
But I want to query relationships in Neo4j.

Question 1: Can you please help me to display relationship between Actors and movie Directors? Actor has relationship with Movie ( r:ACTED_IN {role: 'role_name'} ) and Director has relationship with Movie ( r2:DIRECTED_BY )
How can I display this relationships?

Question 2: How can I write a query that it will show any node (Actor or Director) with all relathionships that this node has?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Q1

```
MATCH path=(a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN {role:'role_name'}]->(m:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED_BY]-(d:Person)
RETURN path
```

Q2

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE (n)-[:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED_BY]-()
RETURN n,[(n)-[r:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED_BY]-(m) | [r,m]]
```